# Fetch data from Firebase - FIRESTORE DB

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have error when I try to fetch data from firebase collection where I storage images and text using them unique postID.. Here is screenshot, hope that somebody know how to fix this.

[image: CODE PICSTURE].

```
set isMyProfile(bool isMyProfile) {}
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((value) {
    print("got user");
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('/profile')
        .doc(value.uid)
        .get()
        .then((uservalue) {
      savedImages = UserModel.fromJson(uservalue.data()).savedImagesPosts;
      savedText = UserModel.fromJson(uservalue.data()).savedTextPosts;
      setState(() {});
      print("got list");
      print(savedImages);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: What's the error message? Note that screenshots of textual contents are not nearly as useful (nor accessible) as having the actual text itself, so I recommend always posting things as text when possible.

Comment: Here Problem is Actually when I try to fetch data, in this case list of saved post, show me this error.. But if I disable this function, then I can't fetch data from Firestore db, and the are already ther added.

Comment: "show me this error" What error?

Comment: Here show that something is wrong "   FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((value) {", on posted image there you can seen that under code is rot line..

Comment: If you hover over that red line, the error shows. Capture that error (in text, no more screenshots please) and edit your question to include it.